# Перевод MediatorLiveData на Flow (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata, kotlinx-coroutines, flow

Есть простенький экран с 6 EditText и кнопкой, которая становится доступной, когда нет ошибок у EditText. Последние 2 поля могут оставаться пустыми. Использую MediatorLiveData, но хочу заменить ее на Flow и combine(). Насколько я понял, combine() может только до 5 потоков объединять, получается нужно как-то свой писать? Или может быть есть другие способы для объединения. Интересно было бы увидеть примеры, как такое возможно перевести на flow, документации и видеороликов на ютуб как-то не хватает, чтобы разобраться с этим

```
    // состояние 
    val state
    get() = MediatorLiveData<OrderCardByPostScreenState>()
        .apply {
            value = OrderCardByPostScreenState()

            addSource(cityInput) { cityState ->
                value = value?.copy(city = cityState) ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }

            addSource(postCodeInput) { postCodeState ->
                value = value?.copy(postCode = postCodeState) ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }

            addSource(streetInput) { streetState ->
                value = value?.copy(street = streetState) ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }

            addSource(houseNumberInput) { houseNumberState ->
                value = value?.copy(houseNumber = houseNumberState) ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }

            addSource(caseNumberInput) { caseNumberState ->
                value = value?.copy(caseNumber = caseNumberState) ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }

            addSource(apartmentNumberInput) { apartmentNumberState ->
                value = value?.copy(apartmentNumber = apartmentNumberState)
                    ?: OrderCardByPostScreenState()
            }
        }

// livedata
private val cityInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>()
private val postCodeInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>()
private val streetInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>()
private val houseNumberInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>()
private val caseNumberInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>()
private val apartmentNumberInput = MutableLiveData<InputState>() 

// Думаю надо заменить чем-то таким 
private val cityInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Initial)
private val postCodeInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Initial)
private val streetInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Initial)
private val houseNumberInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Initial)
private val caseNumberInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Success(""))
private val apartmentNumberInput = MutableStateFlow<InputState>(InputState.Success(""))

// класс для состояния
data class OrderCardByPostScreenState(
val city: InputState = InputState.Initial,
val postCode: InputState = InputState.Initial,
val street: InputState = InputState.Initial,
val houseNumber: InputState = InputState.Initial,
val caseNumber: InputState = InputState.Success(""),
val apartmentNumber: InputState = InputState.Success("")
) {
val isAcceptable: Boolean =
    city is InputState.Success
            && postCode is InputState.Success
            && street is InputState.Success
            && houseNumber is InputState.Success
            && caseNumber is InputState.Success
            && apartmentNumber is InputState.Success
  }

// во фрагменте 
 viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
        btnContinue.isEnabled = state.isAcceptable
        postcodeTextInput.handleInput(state.postCode)
        streetTextInput.handleInput(state.street)
        houseNumberTextInput.handleInput(state.houseNumber)
        caseNumberTextInput.handleInput(state.caseNumber)
        apartmentNumberTextInput.handleInput(state.apartmentNumber)
    }

// расширение для editText
fun EditText.handleInput(state: InputState) {
when (state) {
    is InputState.Initial -> {
        this.error = null
    }
    is InputState.Error -> {
        this.error = resources.getString(state.error)
    }
    is InputState.Success -> {
        this.error = null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть перегрузка combine с произвольным количеством аргументов

Можно сделать так

```
val state = combine(
        cityInput,
        postCodeInput,
        streetInput,
        houseNumberInput,
        caseNumberInput,
        apartmentNumberInput,
    ) { array ->
        OrderCardByPostScreenState(
            city = array[0],
            postCode = array[1],
            street = array[2],
            houseNumber = array[3],
            caseNumber = array[4],
            apartmentNumber = array[5],
        )
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно)